# What is the best way to name a class that does some processing only after post construct?

Tags: java

I have a ValueObject and a builder class in Java . For example Request.java and RequestBuilder.java. RequestBuilder is used to build Request object. When the Request object is constructed I want to call some business logic which has to to be in separate file. This Request object is constructed at many places in the code and I want to call the businness logic( sets/updates some values on Request object) What is the best way to do and name that class? Would RequestFactory.java be appropriate name for it?

Comment: To me `RequestFactory` implies the process of producing a request, not modifying the existing one.

Comment: You need to realize that there is no "best" ways to name something, it's all opinion. `*Processor` from the one answer is good enough, but you are free to name append however much suffixes you want to the name. For instance, since you say "what the object is constructed", it might imply a `*Listener` as well, since object construction might consitute as an event.

Comment: What is the nature of the business logic?  Call it that!  If the business logic does a number of unrelated things, then perhaps it needs to be something like `List<RequestPostConstructProcessor> processors`, where each element does one thing so it can be clearly named.

Comment: Maybe `RequestPostProcessor`?

Answer (score 1):

Name it something like `RequestProcessor`. Don't forget to restrict access to its constructor(s) (`private`, `protected` or package which best suits your needs). `RequestFactory` is more appropriate alternative name for your `RequestBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Shoulf i name the method  as process() inside "*Processor"